# How come Chrome developers aren't taking any initiative against crashsafari.com?

Tags: web-application, web-browser, known-vulnerabilities

How come Chrome developers aren't taking any initiative against crashsafari.com ?
Its a know vulnerability so they should patch it. Shouldn't they ?
By this I  mean they should be 'defensive' and patch the browser, I don't mean they should 'attack the website' - for those who might misunderstand my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two issues for this, [394296](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=394296) and [581237](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=581237), which is a duplicate of 394296.

It's not considered a security issue, the reason given is:

> Removing security bits from the bug. As per http://www.chromium.org/developers/severity-guidelines, this is not a security bug.
>
> Since this is just a generic DoS in the browser due to huge amount of IPC messages coming in, I'm unassigning myself from it for anyone interested in tackling this problem.

From the [linked document](http://www.chromium.org/developers/severity-guidelines):

> The security FAQ covers many of the cases that we do not consider to be security bugs, such as denial of service.

And why don't they consider DOS a security issue? See [here](https://www.chromium.org/Home/chromium-security/security-faq?pli=1#TOC-Are-denial-of-service-issues-considered-security-bugs-):

> **Are denial of service issues considered security bugs?**
>
> No. While they are an inconvenience, we treat them as stability issues rather than security vulnerabilities, and they are not considered under the security VRP. That said, if you find a reproducible crash, we still encourage you to report it. The severity guidelines outline the types of bugs that are considered security vulnerabilities in more detail.

So even though it is not considered a security issue, it is considered a bug and assigned to a developer.